# VLC and default videos directory on DVD drive

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have two hard drives on my laptop: `C` and `D`. The `D` drive is in place of DVD drive.

VLC media player always searches `C:\videos` to load for playing. How can I change this to search `D:\videos` for its file source?

Comment: Do you mean when you do `media->open file` ? This is an explorer window, it should open to the last place you opened a file from ....

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure if that works on removeable drive

Comment: @Kamil I think the OP is saying that they are both Hard drives? *I have two hard drives on my laptop: C and D.*